# Regex in Firebase Storage Rule with .matches(), the regex in regex tools works, but in storage rules not

Tags: regex, firebase-security

I'm trying to check if name of folder that user have to acess contains your uid in firebase storage rules. Only way that I know is with regex and .matches. But all attempts fails even with I test the regex in [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/).

The folder contains two uids, the user need your uid in the folder name for read and write.

`chats/uid1-uid2/`

I try:

`chatName.matches("/"+request.auth.uid+"/");` and another regex tryed, but all fail. I don't know what to think anymore

How could I do the validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

I did not know that fire rules (At least from the storage I knew), have short syntax to split string/array without methods, just array[index1:index2], like in python.

So how the uid is allways fixed size, is just two splits for get uids of uid1-uid2 and compare if uid1 === uid or uid2 === uid